# Ready to run docker images for Spring Cloud Data Flow

Tags: docker, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm looking for ready to run and ready to deploy images for Spring Cloud Data Flow, optimally with HDFS Fuse file system driver. Preferrably with example and documentation.

I already looked for some tutorials - but there are so many steps and configuration options to consider that I'd rather want to start from an existing image / example which may partly fit my needs and make my first steps from there.

What options do I have?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which target runtime (local, CF, Kubernetes, Mesos, YARN) you choose for the Spring Cloud Data Flow, deploying `docker` images is (or yet to be) supported.

For `local` and `CF` deployers, the `docker` image support is yet to be added: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/695

For `kubernetes` you can refer documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_getting_started)

For `mesos` you can refer [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-mesos/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_getting_started)